# Azure - is one 'block blob' seen as one file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**Question background:**

This may be a simple question but I cant find an answer to it. I've just started using Azure storage (for storing images) and want to know if one 'blob' holds a maximum of one file?

This is my container called `fmfcpics`:

[image]

Within the container I have a block blob named `myBlob` and within this I have one image:

[image]

Through the following code, if I upload another image file to the `myBlob` `block blob` then it overwrites the image already in there:

```
 CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");


        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Me\Pictures\Image1.jpg"))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
```

Is this overwriting correct? Or should I be able to store multiple files at the `myBlob`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each blob is a completely separate entity, direct-addressable via uri:

`http(s)://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/blobname`

If you want to manage multiple entities (such as image jpg's in your case), you would upload each one to a separate blob name (and you're free to store as many as you want within a single container, and you may have as many containers as you want).

Note: These are *block* blobs. There are also *page* blobs that have random-access capability, and this is the basis for vhd storage (and in that case, the vhd would have a formatted file system within it, with multiple files).

Comment: many thanks for your great reply. To just confirm for sure I have `myBlob` which is storing `Image.jpg`, I will need a `myBlob1` for `Image1.jpg` then a `myBlob2` for `Image2.jpg` and so on, correct?

Comment: I don't know why you're calling your blobs `myBlob1` and `myBlob2`. Why not just name them `image1.jpg and `image2.jpg?`? At that point, you have `account.blob.core.windows.net/images/image1.jpg, etc.

Answer (score -1):

In blob Azure [Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) you understand how blob service works and the concepts about this storage service.

In some minutes you can use the service easily