# Extract embedded files from azure blob in c#

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, azure-function-app

I have embedded pdf files stored inside a blob file.I want to extract those file from my blob.

below are the thing I have done so far:

1. I have made http trigger function app
2. establish connection with the storage container
3. able to fetch the blob.

get the embedded file I am using following code:

```
namespace PDFDownloader {
  public static class Function1 { [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task <IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {
      log.LogInformation($"GetVolumeData function executed at: 
       {DateTime.Now}");
      try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Parameter.ConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer cloudcontainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(Parameter.SuccessContainer);

        BlobResultSegment resultSegment = await
        cloudcontainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(currentToken: null);
        IEnumerable <IListBlobItem> blobItems = resultSegment.Results;

        string response = "";
        int count = 0;
        //string blobName = "";

        foreach(IListBlobItem item in blobItems) {
          var type = item.GetType();
          if (type == typeof(CloudBlockBlob)) {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
            count++;
            var blobname = blob.Name;
            // response = blobname;
            response = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
            //response = blob.DownloadToStream().Result;
          }
        }

        if (count == 0) {
          return new OkObjectResult("Error : File Not Found !!");
        } else {
          return new OkObjectResult(Convert.ToString(response));
        }
      } catch(Exception ex) {
        log.LogError($ " Function Exception Message: {ex.Message}");
        return new OkObjectResult(ex.Message.ToString());
      } finally {
        log.LogInformation($"Function- ENDED ON : {DateTime.Now}");
      }
    }
  }
```

how can I read embedded files from my blob file response and send it to http?

Comment: please include your entire Function code, including the header (parameters etc)

Comment: @silent I have updated the entire code. please check if you can help me with getting embedded file from blob file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             using Bytescout.PDFExtractor;

            var stream1 = await blob.OpenReadAsync(); //read your blob like 
            this
            attachmentExtractor extractor = new AttachmentExtractor();
                     extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
                     extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";


                     // Load sample PDF document
                     extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(stream1);

                     for (int i = 0; i < extractor.Count; i++)
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine("Saving attachment: " + 
                         extractor.GetFileName(i));
                         // Save attachment to file
                         extractor.Save(i, extractor.GetFileName(i));
                         Console.WriteLine("File size: " + extractor.GetSize(i));
                     }

                     extractor.Dispose();*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that your code needs quite some cleanup and that you should read up on the proper use of async, I believe your actual issue is here:

```
FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(response, FileMode.Open);
```

The `response` object contains the text content of your blob that you downloaded earlier. the Filestream ctor, however, expects a path to a file. Since you do not have a file here, Filestream is not the right thing to use. Either download the blob as a temp file or even directly as a string

Plus, do yourself a favor and switch to the latest version of the Storage Blob SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs#downloading-a-blob).

Comment: yes you right after that line my debugger jumps to Catch block.                                         my blob is in pdf form and in response I need to get content of blob ( content is embedded pdf and xml files). If I dont use Filestream then how should I proceed to read the blob and extract embedded files in it??   I searched a lot but couldnt find any alternative.                                                and my  other question is what should I use instead of passing response in filestream?

Answer (score 0):

Think the one blob is the equivalent of one file(check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926623/azure-is-one-block-blob-seen-as-one-file)).

Check the line:

```
response =  Convert.ToString(blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
```

Is the content of your blob a valid file path ?

Maybe you are not using correctly the constructor of FileStream class *public FileStream (string path, System.IO.FileMode mode)*. This constructor can throw a lot of different exceptions, try to find [yours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_).

Also, as it was recommended in a previous answer, it is worth using the **Azure.Storage.Blobs** package based on SDK version 12, now you are using the SDK version 11(Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob).

Comment: i am not able to save the blob locally so which path should I provide in filestream .... Can you  help me with what should i provide there?  Is there anyway without saving locally i can provide path directly of my blob?